# Why mark function argument as volatile

Tags: c, parameters, volatile

I am currently reading the [PostgreSql](https://github.com/postgres/postgres) code. Here is an excerpt from the buffer manager:

```
static void WaitIO(volatile BufferDesc *buf);
static bool StartBufferIO(volatile BufferDesc *buf, bool forInput);
static void TerminateBufferIO(volatile BufferDesc *buf, bool clear_dirty,
```

I know the volatile keyword is usually used for device drivers and in embedded systems. There is an explanation of the keyword.

> When the keyword volatile is used in the type definition it is giving an indication to the compiler on how it should handle the variable. Primarily it is telling the compiler that the value of the variable may change at any time as a result of actions external to the program or current line of execution.
> ([Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20140329054504/http://www.cognitus.net:80/html/tutorial/usingVolatile.html))

So why are certain function arguments declared as volatile? I don't expect that DMA changes the pointer location. So what happens here?

Comment: Not sure its worth another question, but interested to know why you might write `void func(int volatile arg);`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`volatile BufferDesc *buf` means that the data that `buf` *points to* is volatile, not that the pointer contained by `buf` is volatile. (That would be `BufferDesc * volatile buf`.)

From [the page you linked to](https://web.archive.org/web/20140329054504/http://www.cognitus.net:80/html/tutorial/usingVolatile.html):

> On the other hand, if you have a pointer variable where the address itself was volatile but the memory pointed to was not then we have:
>
> ```
> int * volatile x;
> ```

Re this part of your question:

> So why are certain function arguments declared as volatile?

Presumably because the data it points to can change in a way that the compiler wouldn't necessarily know about. The `volatile` keyword is there to prevent the compiler applying optimizations that assume the data doesn't change in ways it doesn't know about.

Comment: If the issue was a concurrency issue, the variable would have been protected with a mutex, for instance. The volatile keyword request the compiler to avoid optimisations related to that variable. Thus it will reload it from memory every time its is read in the program . Which is required when a device driver just finished writing content in the memory buffer. TerminateBufferIO() could be the callback invoked when the device is done. Volatile keywords helps in enforcing the loading of the content from the memory and not from the cache level only (which could be not up to date).

Answer (score 8):

> I don't expect that DMA changes the pointer location.

Not the location, but maybe the content. And that's exactly what it is about...

Answer (score 1):

Databases implementation does not rely on the OS buffers&caches when accessing files. They prefer to implement they own cache system and **get direct access to the file on the physical disk**, for reliability issues: data MUST to be flushed to the physical disk. (They use the O_DIRECT option to perform direct access to physical disk.)

The 3 functions you are showing us make me think of asynchronous handling of data coming from the disk. (StartBufferIO(), TerminatedBufferIO() and so on). Honestly I am not sure of what is their purpose, but based on what I know about databases implementation, and those function names, I would say that the buffer content might be modified by the "disk" itself with data from the file on the disk (or whatever device), and therefore needs to be flaged as **volatile**.

This hypothesis joins your usual interpretation of what the **volatile** keyword is usually used for: device drivers.

Answer (score 0):

DMA isn't the only reason to use "volatile".  It's also useful for multithreaded and shared memory applications, where another thread may change memory referenced by this code.  I'm sure that PostgreSql is multi-threaded, so this is a likely reason why volatile is being used here.

Comment: Using volatile for thread issues is asking for it.  You should be using a thread primitive for sync in that case.

Comment: Just because you've used a mutex to guard against race conditions doesn't mean that your compiler isn't going to try to optimize its access to the shared variables.  That being said, sync primitives are function calls, and the compiler can't make any assumptions about changes to non-local variables around a function call.  So in general, you're right.

Comment: The thing about volatile in C is that it doesn't do what you think volatile does from a multi-threading perspective unless the computer has exactly one CPU with one core. So it's rarely useful on modern devices, and even if it is for a given device, it's not very forwards compatible, as the next gen of that device may switch to multiple cores.

Answer (score 0):

One thing a compiler usually does when optimising is removing dead code, so if you do some operations with a variable that its never read neither and its result is useless compiler will probably just remove it, as well as removing the rest of operations that affects it. That behaviour can be very annoying when your debug a code ore your are performing some kind of benchamrks. If you declare as volatile a variable you alert the compiler it could be used by external libraries or programs, among other implications the keyword may have. Then it should never treat it as dead code.